# Claims GetUserId is null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, owin

I hope you're all great, this time I'm here to ask an issue that I can't figure it out and it's about Identity, the thing is I want to get de User Id from the Claims principal or whereever it is, right now the only thing that I have is

```
var principal = ClaimsPrincipal.Current;
        var id1 = principal.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ValueType == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
```

but when I try to get the UserId and I go to the information inside the claims I can't find the value even if I saved it in the AuthorizationTicket at login.

I'm working with MVC template and Web api service My service is hosted in IIS and with it I manage the authentication with an accountcontroller via Token

this is my AuthenticationProperties

```
public static AuthenticationProperties CreateProperties(string userName, string userid)
    {
        IDictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "userName", userName }, { "userId", userid } };
        return new AuthenticationProperties(data);
    }
```

and my GrantResourceOwnerCredentiales

```
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        var userManager = context.OwinContext.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        //var userManager = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ApplicationUserManager>();

        AppJobSeeker user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);

        if (user == null)
        {
            context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
            return;
        }

        ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager, OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        ClaimsIdentity cookiesIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        AuthenticationProperties properties = CreateProperties(user.UserName, user.Id);
        AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, properties);
        context.Validated(ticket);
        context.Request.Context.Authentication.SignIn(cookiesIdentity);...
```

And I have a method which creates a AuthenticationTicket and it receive the UserName and the UserId as well

```
private void CreateTicket(SignInResult result, SignInModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        //Let's keep the user authenticated in the MVC webapp.
        //By using the AccessToken, we can use User.Identity.Name in the MVC controllers to make API calls.
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(result.AccessToken, model.RememberMe);

        //Create an AuthenticationTicket to generate a cookie used to authenticate against Web API.
        //But before we can do that, we need a ClaimsIdentity that can be authenticated in Web API.
        var claims = new[]
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, result.UserName), //Name is the default name claim type, and UserName is the one known also in Web API.
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, result.UserId), //If you want to use User.Identity.GetUserId in Web API, you need a NameIdentifier claim.
        };

        //Generate a new ClaimsIdentity, using the DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie authenticationType.
        //This also matches what we've set up in Web API.
        var authTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(new ClaimsIdentity(claims, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie), new AuthenticationProperties
        {
            ExpiresUtc = result.Expires,
            IsPersistent = model.RememberMe,
            IssuedUtc = result.Issued,
            RedirectUri = returnUrl
        });
```

...

Everithing looks fine when I do the login but when a I go to another controller  I can't retreive the UserId

Answer (score 1):

Have you added the **[Authorize]** attribute to your controller?

```
[Authorize]
public class AuthorizeController : ApiController
{
   public Task<IHttpActionResult> GetUserId()
   {
       return Ok(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId());
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Rikard, I solved the problem, I was using GetUserId at the wrong place. (MVC side) when I have to use it at the WebApi side.